# right align li in flex ul

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<ul class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-pill tabs-moible-hidden" id="tabs-moible">
        <li class="uk-active">
            <a href="#">Web development </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile Apps </a>
        </li>

</ul>
```

here is my css

```
.uk-subnav-pill {
    margin-top: -47px;
}
.uk-subnav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 30px 10px;
    margin-top: -53px;
}
```

and for `li` i have

```
.uk-subnav > * {
    flex: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

currently it look like this

[image]

the tabs are `li` tags ... i want them to align on the right side

i'e tried to add

```
 justify-content: space-between;
```

to `ul` , but it just spreads them in the with ... like align them in the center 
i also tried adding `margin-left: auto`  to `li` element but ended with the same result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the flex-end to pull them right.

```css
.uk-subnav-pill {
    margin-top: -47px;
}
.uk-subnav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 30px 10px;
   justify-content: flex-end;

}
.uk-subnav > * {
    flex: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-pill tabs-moible-hidden" id="tabs-moible">
        <li class="uk-active">
            <a href="#">Web development </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile Apps </a>
        </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:** You can use float and set it to right for you .uk-subnav-pill :

```css
.uk-subnav-pill {
    margin-top: 0px; /* changed */
    float:right
}
.uk-subnav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 30px 10px;
    margin-top: 0px; /* changed */
}
.uk-subnav > * {
    flex: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-pill tabs-moible-hidden" id="tabs-moible">
        <li class="uk-active">
            <a href="#">Web development </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile Apps </a>
        </li>

</ul>
```

**Method 2:** You can use direction and set it to rtl (right to left):
You can use float and set it to right for you .uk-subnav-pill :

```css
.uk-subnav-pill {
    margin-top: 0px; /* changed */
    direction: rtl;
}
.uk-subnav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 30px 10px;
    margin-top: 0px; /* changed */
}
.uk-subnav > * {
    flex: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-pill tabs-moible-hidden" id="tabs-moible">
        <li class="uk-active">
            <a href="#">Web development </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Mobile Apps </a>
        </li>

</ul>
```